# New kitchen, new home runs for appliances...lights flicker, what could be the cause?

Tags: electrical

We have a newly renovated kitchen. All the appliances are on their own breaker (according to code).  We also have recessed lights installed which I believe may be using the old wiring.

One day we had many appliances going and the lights flickered once really quickly.  It seemed almost as if the power was going to go out...that kind of flicker.

We didn't think much of it. It happened again after 5 - 10 minutes.  My wife thinks it's because she turned on our new exhaust hood to max.

We haven't been able to replicate issue.

What could have been the cause? Is there a way to test for the cause/issue?

**update 1/30**
We have a 200A panel. 
We have a gas range & a gas tankless. We have a washer and gas dryer. All on separate circuits.

Comment: What size electrical service do you have? Do you have an electric range? At the time of the flicker, was the A/C or electric furnace running? Do you have an electric or gas water heater? What other large electrical loads could have been running at the time?

Comment: This *could* have been a voltage drop before your meter from the power lines. For years we have had that and I am almost certain it is on the incoming line probably from switching at sub-stations or transmission lines. It could be my service drop is damaged. If it was a loose connection in your new wiring, it will surely recur and soon.

Answer (score 1):

Put a peak load on the circuit and measure the voltage. If the voltage droops more than the permitted droop of 5% (that's 6 volts on 120V) -- less is preferable for incandescent lights and motors -- then you definitely have excessive resistance in the circuit wiring.

And then have to check that the wires are properly rated for the load and the length of run and also have to inspect every junction box on that circuit and check each connection -- clean the wires, replace the connection device (wire nut, etc.), and retighten them preferably with a torque driver.